# tensorflow keras fit, input validation data (data, (target1,target2)) ,got error :'expected no data, but got:'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Build a subclassed model with multiple outputs, use tensorflow datasets as input. Custom defined datasets.

Use keras fit to train model.

When i only use train dataset, it could run. But once i use same type datasets as validation input, it goes wrong like:
     'Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:'

Data type is like 'tuple(data, (target[0], target[1]))'

tensorflow-gpu==1.12, tensorflow.keras

Wrong information

```
File "/home/god/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1574, in fit
steps=validation_steps)    

File "/home/god/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 992, in _standardize_user_data
class_weight, batch_size)

File "/home/god/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1154, in _standardize_weights
exception_prefix='target')

File "/home/god/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 257, in standardize_input_data
'expected no data, but got:', data)

ValueError: ('Error when checking model target: expected no data, but got:', (<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:1' shape=(16, 16, 513) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext_1:2' shape=(16, 16, 513) dtype=float32>))
```

simplification code cause same error

```
import tensorflow as tf


class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16)
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape, input_shape

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        out1 = self.dense1(inputs)
        out2 = self.dense2(inputs)
        return out1, out2


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (tf.constant(0., shape=[1024, 16]), (tf.constant(0., shape=[1024, 16]), tf.constant(0., shape=[1024, 16])))).repeat().batch(32)

valid_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (tf.constant(0., shape=[128, 16]), (tf.constant(0., shape=[128, 16]), tf.constant(0., shape=[128, 16])))).repeat(1).batch(32)

model = Model()
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4),
    loss=[tf.keras.losses.mse, tf.keras.losses.mse],
    loss_weights=[1, 1]
)
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=valid_dataset,
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=30,
    validation_steps=4,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras is not PyTorch, you should not subclass model without a very advanced reason.

```
inputs = Input(input_shape)
out1 = Dense(16)(inputs)
out2 = Dense(16)(inputs)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, [out1,out2])
```

Separate `x` and `y` when training:

```
x_train = your_tuple[0]
y_train = your_tuple[1]

model.fit(x_train, y_train, ....)
```

Comment: I am curious about when we should use submodel. Many say that you should consider it when you have multiple input and want to build model based on input schema. What is your idea about this?

Comment: @G_cy, when I answered this, subclassing was about starting in Keras, but it became more widespread later. To be fair, without looking deeply into it, I don't see a difference that makes it worth the extra code. Maybe (didn't check) it accepts free functions (outside keras layers) inside the model's `call` method, and this would spare a few `Lambda` layers that would be needed with functional API. I never needed to subclass a model in Keras for regular use.

Comment: It might be better for save/load purposes, if you take advantage of the `get_config` method to store custom parameters that might be important for the model's reconstruction. I remember I had problems with some vars I used in lambda layers and were not loaded correctly later. I "believe" that subclassing and adding those vars to the config might solve this.

Comment: I agree with the save/load part. I remember in early  version of tf 2 I couldn't load my model with custom metrics.

Comment: As far as I know, you must declare the custom metrics in a custom objects dictionary for any kind of model load.